# How to use a Constant value of a class field in a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, class-constants

I would like to use some java class constant value in my XML layout. Is that possible?

## java class

```
public class ConstantKey {

   public static final String COUNTRY_CODE            = "+00";
   public static final STRING COUNTRY_NAME            = "USA";

}
```

## Xml layout

```
    <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="ConstantKey.COUNTRY_NAME"/>
```

Comment: Layouts aren't dynamic. Meaning that they don't interact with Java code. You can do the opposite, though. Define a constant in a resource file. It can be then accessed by both resorces and Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

1) If the strings are constant all through, you could add them as string resources inside `strings.xml`. This way they're accessed from both layout or java code.

2) If the values depend on a network call or are dynamically computed, I suggest using `DataBinding` in andorid, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47744774/4508759) for small implementation example.